# MongoDB, how to design the database

Tags: mongodb

As working with a deeply nested array is very difficult in MongoDB, what is a good design when you have document that look like

```
{
  "name" : "in",
  "states" : [ {"name" : "up", 
                "cities" : [ {"name" : "dp", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] }, 
                            {"name" : "mo", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] } ]}, 
               {"name" : "tn", 
               "cities" : [ {"name" : "ab", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] }, 
                            {"name" : "cd", "places" : [ {"name" : "pvr"}, {"name" : "lpu"} ] } ]} 
             ]
  }
```

Comment: Your data model should be built around your use cases. Can you provide details on how you plan to both read from and write to this data set?

Comment: It is also worth giving the following a read which provides example of different data model patterns using MongoDB: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/

Comment: My use cases involves a lot a addition and updation of "cities" and "places". Mostly, I am finding it difficult to edit "places" based on the conditions of "states" and "cities".